# Laravel installer keeps installing 5.5 instead of 5.6

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I installed php 7.2.2  / apache 2.4 and mysql-5.7 on windows 10.

I want to install laravel 5.6

first:

```
1.  composer clear-cache
2.  composer update
3.  composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

php -v:

```
PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Jan 31 2018 19:31:17) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

and `Laravel Installer 2.0.1`

I try this (according to the laravel doc 5.6):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

But it install laravel 5.5.28

Why does composer keep installing laravel 5.5?

Comment: 5.5 is not part of the distribution source yet.  add `dev-develop` to the end of your composer command.

Comment: 5.6 is not official release yet so you will get last official version from composer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 5.6 was not officially released until today (2018-02-07).

Now that it has been officially released, the Laravel installer and the composer create-project will use 5.6, instead of 5.5.

If you'd like to install a version that is not the current version, you need to specify the version to install as the last parameter to `composer create-project`.

For example, now that 5.6 has been released and is the current version, if you wanted to create a 5.5 project, you would add "5.5" to the composer statement:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

1- Your server php version must be ^7.1.3

2- You must Reinstall composer and select php ^7.1.3 in installation steps.
then use command below to install version 5.6 of Laravel

```
 composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.6.*" Your-Project-Name
```

Or use command below to install latest version of Laravel

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Your-Project-Name --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name-here dev-develop
```