# Can't install laravel 5.6 using composer

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.6

I've been trying to install laravel 5.6 using composer but it is always installing version 5.5. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612380/laravel-installer-keeps-installing-5-5-instead-of-5-6) question which says this problem was fixed but trying that solution does not solve my problem. I tried doing

```
composer -vvv create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel fullstackart "5.6"
```

but got the following exception

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.6.
```

I also tried

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name-here dev-develop
```

and had a similar error saying package not found.

Has anyone else had this problem and found any solution which I have not mentioned here? Would greatly appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? Laravel 5.6 requires `>= 7.1.3`, while Laravel 5.5 requires `>= 7.0.0`.

Comment: @robert I think you are right, I have php 7.0.30 installed currently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer in case the comments are ever deleted. This issue was due to Laravel 5.6 requiring PHP >= 7.1.3, but the OP had 7.0.30 installed.

Since the PHP version didn't meet the minimum requirements for Laravel 5.6, Laravel 5.5 was installed.